# How to load images to page from image folder dynamically

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I'm using MVC4 c#.  I'm trying to load images that I need to show on a page dynamically by reading the content of the image folder and doing a foreach loop.  I'm not sure how to read the content of the folder which is called ImageFiles which is located in the project and not the c:\ of the server.  This is what I used and it works on my local computer but when I use `../../filename/filename/ImageFiles` as the path it does not work.  Can anyone help?

```
string filePath = @"../../Content/EventFiles/ImageFiles";
DirectoryInfo directory = new DirectoryInfo(filePath);

@foreach (FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles())
{
    <\a href="../../Content/EventFiles/ImageFiles/@file.Name">
       <\img src="/Content/EventFiles/ImageFiles/@file.Name" />
    <\/a>
}
```

Comment: I have no idea how this would be working for you in any environment, but you are going to want to look at `Server.MapPath()`

Comment: One strategy would be to do a determine the filesystem path of the image, and compare it to the filesystem path of the website root for resolution. I find it easier doing it that way once I get into the System.IO namespace. But I should have more fully explained that in my initial comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is Server.MapPath().  For desktop applications DirectoryInfo() works but for a web application I had to use Server.MapPath().

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are not referencing the filePath correctly.

Try this one on your View..

```
@{DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Content/EventFiles/ImageFiles")));}
@foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles())
{
    <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/EventFiles/ImageFiles/" + file.Name)" />
}
```